# Can not access MongoDB in command prompt by using command --dbpath

Tags: mongodb

I can not access MongoDB in my command prompt even if i have already set path in environment variables path setting.I have installed MongoDB  in my c drive.i created one new folder and copied  its path.I oped command prompt and typed command `mongod --dbpath folder-path-name` and when run this it gave me the error `mongod` is not internal or external command.In one of my win-7 systme it is running nicely.But here i tried in windows-8 system.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can't access OR can't install mongodb ?

Comment: @AmanAggarwal: Can not access.